# Can we write CSS for a label based on the attributes of its "for" attribute's value?

Tags: label-for

I want to write css for the labels of checkboxes based on checkbox enabled/disabled. I know the following methods, but I'm not satisfied with these.

Method1:

```
label[for="something"] {
   /* woohoo! */
}
```

- I want to write a generalized css. I do not want to repeat for every checkbox like above.

Method2:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:enabled+label{ font-weight: bold; }
```

- this one directly picks the sibling and is not based on "for". I want to pick the label specifically that is associated with the checkbox and leave it alone if the label is not 'for' that checkbox.

How can I apply css based on a label's "for" attribute?

Answer (score 2):

think your after the :checked pseudo-class rather than :enabled

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {}
```

The above would select a label who was the next sibling after a checked input of type checkbox